# What wrong with this migration

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-migrations

Hello I am practicing Laravel now and I'm doing some migration but when I try to run my migration I got this following errors.

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (
  `sample`.`#sql-1d0c_20f`, CONSTRAINT `products_product_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_type_id`) REFERENCE
  S `product_types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_product_type_id_foreig
  n` foreign key (`product_type_id`) references `product_types` (`id`) on delete cascade)

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (
  `sample`.`#sql-1d0c_20f`, CONSTRAINT `products_product_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_type_id`) REFERENCE
  S `product_types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

this is my my **product_types** migration code

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('product_type')->unique();
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->nullable(false); //1 for active 2 for inactive
        $table->timestamps('created_at');

    });


}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('product_types');

}
```

Adding FK constrain in **product table**

```
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
     /**
     * Drop column type in products table
     */
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('type');
    });

    /**
     * Create column product_type in products table
     */
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('product_type_id')->unsigned()->after('price');
        $table->foreign('product_type_id')->references('id')->on('product_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{

    /**
     * Drop column product_type_id in products table
     */
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('product_type_id');
        $table->dropColumn('product_type_id');
    });

    /**
     * Re-create column type in products table
     */
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('type')->after('price');
    });
}
```

Comment: The order of executing those migration files is important...product_types needs to be before product table

Comment: is there no other way? I created the producty_types table 1st before I added new column for product_type_id in product table.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the migrations order, being sure product_types is before product table.